# Do Not Track implementation in express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to add a function called "consent" that uses the functionality called Do Not Track (DNT) from browsers. The function role is to add Google analytics on rendered pages when DNT is not active or its state is '1'. Here is what I have come up with in my Nodejs express app:

```
var concent = function(req, res) {
if(req.header.dnt == '0' || req.header.dnt == null)
{return true;}
else{return false;}
}
```

The view looks like this in Jade:

```
if consent
  script.
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-11111111-1', 'yourdomain.com');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Unfortunately when I test it it doesn't appear to work...

Comment: You misspelled "consent"

Comment: Okay, so you have the concent (which SLaks is right, you probably meant consent) function. Are you ever actually using this function? I'd probably set this up as a middle-ware that added some parameters to the objects that get passed to your Jade templates.

Comment: Anytime you have `if (condition) return true; else return false;` you should probably do `return condition`.  So in your case `return (req.header.dnt == '0' || req.header.dnt == null)`;

Answer (score 0):

[*req.header*](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.get) is a function, not an object. At least for me the actual headers are stored under *req.headers* (plural s) - but that seems to be a node.js native behaviour: [HTTP request.headers](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_headers).

```
var consent = function(req, res) {
    var DNT = req.header('dnt');
    return typeof DNT == 'undefined' || DNT == '0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to existing knowledge. As of express 4.x, this has been aliased as `req.get([header])`. Replace `[header]` with the name of the header that you are looking for. Hope this saves some keystrokes for anyone.